# Creating circle around point with size relative to field attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, polygon-creation, circle

I'm using QGIS to create tree surveys. When I return to the office and download my tree points into QGIS I would like to create an expression that uses the `"DBH"` (a field collected numerical attribute field) to create a circle around each point relative to the size of the `"DBH"`. So that, X `"DBH"` >>> (X*12)*1.25 CRZ where CRZ is the radius of the circle.

Is there an expression I can add to the symbology that would do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
@Taras answered with a processing algorithm, to create a polygon layer with a circular buffer around each of your points with the desired size.

Alternatively, if you only want to *display* the circles, you can use a Data Defined override in the renderer (symbology) for the existing layer.

In the renderer, use a Simple marker as the symbol layer type. Choose the shape in the selection on the bottom to be a circle. Set the size to be in map units, and specify a Data defined override (icon to the right of the field) with an expression of `("DBH"*12)*1.25*2`. Here I've taken my interpretation of what your wrote for the expression, but multiplied by 2 since the symbol size is diameter, not radius.

Comment: Seeing your comment on the other answer - I think these will export as lines in DXF, but don't use DXF or Civil3D so you'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) geoalgorithm

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And one more by means of the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) geoalgorithm with a [`make_circle()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-circle) function

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Use the ["Rectangles, ovals, diamonds (variable)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds-variable) geoalgorithm with *'Width'* and *'Height'* will match a corresponding field attribute

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Taras, do you know if these symbology attributes will export as lines when I export the data as a DXF to bring into Civil3D?

Comment: Probably yes, but I will suggest asking it as a new question on the GIS SE.